# Detect login in HttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, httpmodule

I'm developing an HttpModule and I need to detect a login and logout process. How can I do this?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is too vague to be able to provide a meaningful answer. Please add details, sample code, what you've tried, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is it you means ?

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += new EventHandler(context_PreRequestHandlerExecute);
    }
    void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpContext context = app.Context;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        if (IsLoginPage(context))
        {
            // ...
        }
        else if (IsLogoutPage(context))
        { 
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. I will test this code and I will update this thead.

Comment: Hello Scott, I need to know the IsLoginPage and IsLogoutPage. In some ways, I can know the login process through IsNewSession but, if I use forms authentication, there's no session.

Comment: Sorry , I donnt know what you want ..  If you want to get the online users , you can use global.asa   , and use session_start and session_end

Comment: Hello Scott. Thank you for your help. I'm creating an httpmodule to loggin the attempt to login/logout (ok or wrong) and for testing this module I'm using a site creating with visual studio 2010 template. The standar web application in VS 2010. In this site, I have created an user and when I try to login, the session_start in global.asax is not fire. When this user is login ok, there no session created. Any ideas? Thank you